# Catching NotImplementedError not executing code in except block

Tags: django, django-orm

PostgreSQL is able to have `.distint('field name')` database queries, however Sqlite isn't, so I created a try/except block which should run a more simple query if the user is using sqlite3.

```
try:
    qs = qs.filter(tag__istartswith=self.q).order_by('tag').distinct('tag')
except NotImplementedError:
    qs = qs.filter(tag__istartswith=self.q)
```

So if the user is using Sqlite I would expect the simple query in the except block to get executed, however the exception is thrown and the simple query never gets executed:

```
raise NotImplementedError('DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend')
NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend
```

Do you have any idea why this isn't working as expected?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/optimization/#understand-queryset-evaluation) and the error is not raised while constructing the query, but when you actually evaluate it.

You can try [forcing your query to be evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) to catch the exception:

```
try:
    qs = qs.filter(tag__istartswith=self.q).order_by('tag').distinct('tag')
    dummy_boolean_var = qs.exists()
except NotImplementedError:
    qs = qs.filter(tag__istartswith=self.q)
```

EDIT: Apparently my untested version did not work as the assignment in the `except` clause tries to modify the original query. This is the working version as tested by OP:

```
try:
    qa = qs
    qs = qs.filter(tag__istartswith=self.q).order_by('tag').distinct(‌​'tag')
    dummy_boolean_var = qs.exists()
except NotImplementedError:
    qs = qa
    qs = qs.filter(tag__istartswith=self.q)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It works, although I had to make a small change. When the first (try) qs query fails, that causes the second (except) qs to fail as it seems the first qs attempt altered qs. Therefore I need to do something like this:  
`try:\n  qa = qs\n qs = qs.filter(tag__istartswith=self.q).order_by('tag').distinct('tag')\n
    dummy_boolean_var = qs.exists()\n
except NotImplementedError:\n qs = qa\n
    qs = qs.filter(tag__istartswith=self.q)`. Sorry for the bad formatting, not sure how to improve it.

Comment: @TomBrock Thanks for the update, I edited my answer and included your working version to help future visitors.